# Rotating a sprite in HaxeFlixel

Tags: rotation, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm having trouble with something very simple in HaxeFlixel, but I can't find one reference to it anywhere online.

All I need to do is rotate a `FlxSprite`. There are multiple references online to a `.rotation` value that can be set, but my sprite does not have access to this for some reason.

Can anyone help out here, I have no idea where to go from here.

The graphics I'm creating is of type `Player`, which extends `FlxSprite` and is created with `loadGraphic()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FlxObject` (which `FlxSprite` extends) has an [`angle`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxObject.html#angle) property. Use it to rotate your sprites.